# Debugging SearchBox Places results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm following the simple SearchBox example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox#try-it-yourself

Everything is loading correctly but when I type in the SearchBox, no results are listed. I can see .pac-container  at the bottom of the page and when I type in SearchBox, .pac-container changes from:

```
<div class="pac-container pac-logo" style="display: none;"></div>
```

to:

```
<div class="pac-container pac-logo" style="display: none; width: 298px; position: absolute; left: 691px; top: 484px;"></div>
```

Which shows it responding but I think it remains "display:none" because there is no results being returned, the div remains empty.

Does anyone know how I can debug the SearchBox response? I'm not sure how to check why no results are being returned.

Comment: Did you generate an API key and enabled Maps API JS and Places API on this project?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem!! I had only the Google Maps JavaScript API enabled. Enabling Places API fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to debug requests you have to open the browser console and check the Network activity when you type something in SearchBox.

You should see requests similar to 
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetQueryPredictions?1sbarce&4sen-GB&6m6&1m2&1d-33.89730187304173&2d151.1460289306641&2m2&1d-33.840288607560595&2d151.29297106933598&15e3&key=AIzaSyDIJ9XX2ZvRKCJcFRrl-lRanEtFUow4piM&callback=*xdc*._wzqudm&token=104072](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetQueryPredictions?1sbarce&4sen-GB&6m6&1m2&1d-33.89730187304173&2d151.1460289306641&2m2&1d-33.840288607560595&2d151.29297106933598&15e3&key=AIzaSyDIJ9XX2ZvRKCJcFRrl-lRanEtFUow4piM&callback=_xdc_._wzqudm&token=104072)

You can see response codes and response body as shown in the screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szyyw.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG5jQ.jpg